# JNIEnv call from within monodroid application

Tags: xamarin.android, jnienv

This is the Java class i'm accessing through JNIEnv in my monodroid application

```java
package mypackage;

import android.util.Log;

public class JavaScriptInterface {


    public String submitAns = "";

    // The JNI in the original question uses a default constructor.
    // Either provide one explicitly or use the implicit one...
    public JavaScriptInterface() 
    {

    }   

    public String getSelctd()
    {
        return submitAns;
    }
}
```

I'm able to instantiate the class by the following statements:

```cs
Java.Lang.Object jclassWrp_;

IntPtr JavaScriptInterface_Class = JNIEnv.FindClass("mypackage.JavaScriptInterface");

IntPtr JavaScriptInterface_ctor = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(JavaScriptInterface_Class, "<init>", "()V"); //(Landroid/context/Context;)V

IntPtr jsInterfaceinstance_ = JNIEnv.NewObject(JavaScriptInterface_Class, JavaScriptInterface_ctor);

jclassWrp_ = new Java.Lang.Object(jsInterfaceinstance_, JniHandleOwnership.TransferGlobalRef);
```

But when i try to create the object to access the **getSelctd()** method:

```
IntPtr ipApid = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(jclassWrp_, "getSelctd", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
```

It throws NoSuchMethodExist Exception...
Please tell me whether i'm doing it the right way and what i'm missing here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm able to instantiate the class by the following statements:

```cs
Java.Lang.Object jclassWrp_;
IntPtr JavaScriptInterface_Class = JNIEnv.FindClass("mypackage.JavaScriptInterface");
```

JNI use should use JNI conventions, thus `mypackage/JavaScriptInterface` (note `/` instead of `.`).

```
IntPtr JavaScriptInterface_ctor = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(JavaScriptInterface_Class, "<init>", "()V");
IntPtr jsInterfaceinstance_ = JNIEnv.NewObject(JavaScriptInterface_Class, JavaScriptInterface_ctor);
jclassWrp_ = new Java.Lang.Object(jsInterfaceinstance_, JniHandleOwnership.TransferGlobalRef);
```

`JNIEnv.NewObject()` returns a local ref, not a global ref, so you want `JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef`.

> But when i try to create the object to access the getSelctd() method:

```cs
IntPtr ipApid = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(jclassWrp_, "getSelctd", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
```

`JNIEnv.GetMethodID()` takes a class handle, not an instance. Firstly, the above shouldn't compile (`Java.Lang.Object` != `IntPtr`). Secondly, `jclassWrp` contains a `mypackage.JavaScriptInterface` instance, not the `mypackage.JavaScriptInterface` Class instance.

Instead, do:

```cs
IntPtr ipApid = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(JavaScriptInterface_Class, "getSelctd", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
```

Finally, don't forget to `JNIEnv.DeleteGlobalRef(JavaScriptInterface_Class)` when you don't need it anymore, otherwise you'll leak the gref.

Complete code:

```cs
// FindClass() returns a gref; must be freed (see below)
IntPtr JavaScriptInterface_Class     = JNIEnv.FindClass("mypackage/JavaScriptInterface");

// MethodIDs do not need to be freed
IntPtr JavaScriptInterface_ctor      = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(JavaScriptInterface_Class,
        "<init>", "()V");
IntPtr JavaScriptInterface_getSelctd = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(JavaScriptInterface_Class,
        "getSelctd", "()Ljava/lang/String;");

// JNIEnv.NewObject() & JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod() return lrefs; freed below
IntPtr lrefInstance                  = JNIEnv.NewObject(JavaScriptInterface_Class,
        JavaScriptInterface_ctor);
IntPtr lrefSelectd                   = JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod(jsInterfaceinstance_, ipApid);

// JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef causes lrefSelectd to be released for us
string selected                      = JNIEnv.GetString(lrefSelectd, JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);

// Resource cleanup
JNIEnv.DeleteLocalRef(lrefInstance);
JNIEnv.DeleteGlobalRef(JavaScriptInterface_Class);
```